# Which Babel plugin allows me to do `import { Header, Footer } from "components"`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, directory-structure

I have my Next.js project set up with the following folder structure:

```
- src
  - components
    - Header
      - Header.tsx
      - Header.styles.ts
      - index.ts ( `export { Header } from "./Header"` )
    - Footer
      - Footer.tsx
      - Footer.styles.ts
      - index.ts ( `export { Footer} from "./Footer"` )
    - index.ts ( `export { Footer } from "./Footer"` and `export { Header } from "./Header"` )
```

I've also configured Babel with the following configuration:

```
{
  "plugins": [
   [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["src"],
        "extensions": [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

This setup allows me to do the following: `import { Header, Footer } from "components"`. I'm looking to get rid of all these `index.ts` files. All the index files in the component folders contain `export { COMPONENT_NAME } from "./COMPONENT_NAME"`. And the universal index file in the component folder also contains `export { COMPONENT_NAME } from "./COMPONENT_NAME"`, for each of the components.

**How can I configure Babel to allow me to do `import { Header, Footer } from "components"` and have it expand this to:**

```
import { Header } from "components/Header/Header"
import { Footer} from "components/Footer/Footer"
```

I'm using TypeScript so any help with how to configure this in `tsconfig.json` would be appreciated!

Comment: you should keep your index file, this is a best practice.

Comment: @JoeLloyd would you please explain why it is a best practice? It causes a lot of chaos in my IDE, as there are many `index.ts` files. Also, whenever I add a new component I have to add an export to the universal `index.ts ` file. This doesn't seem optimal. I also don't like importing with `import { Header } from "components/Header/Header"`
and `import { Footer} from "components/Footer/Footer"`. Is better to keep all index files and do what I described in the question, or should i remove all index files and use these long, separate imports?